# Beamer xelatex images not show

Tags: beamer, xetex, org-mode

```
% Created 2019-11-13 Wed 10:48
% Intended LaTeX compiler: xelatex
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Source Han Serif CN}
\setCJKsansfont{Source Han Serif CN}
\setCJKmonofont{Cascadia Code}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\date{2019-11-12}
\title{ImageTest}
\author{Jilen} % BAD ORDER XXX
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={Jilen Jilen},
 pdftitle={ImageTest},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 27.0.50 (Org mode 9.2.6)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}[label={sec:org407d30b}]{Beamer image test}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{foo.png}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This beamer presentation is exported by org-mode. 
But the image is not show.
I tried both png/jpeg/bmp, no lucky.

Log related to image

```
File: """foo".png Graphic file (type bmp)
<"""foo".png>
 [2

]
```

> Version: This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)

Comment: Welcome! The graphic is of type BMP and you cannot use it. You need an image in a supported format. (You can't just change the extension and say it is `foo.png`. You need it to really be a PNG or whatever.) You should also edit your preamble, since its toxicity level is currently quite high. Don't load: `hyperref`, `longtable`, `wrapfig`, `graphicx`, `inputenc` at a minimum. `hyperref` and `graphicx` are loaded by `beamer`. `longtable` and `wrapfig` make no sense with `beamer` and `inputenc` isn't relevant for XeTeX. Do you really need `\captionof` in a presentation?

Comment: @cfr That is a png image, I am pretty sure.

Comment: The error says it is bmp. So, if it is png, there is something very wrong with it.

Comment: @cfr Both png and bmp and jpeg are treated as bitmap image, in latex I think. And that packages actually are imported by org-mode automatically.

Comment: The quotes around foo look wrong. Is your system up-to-date?  There has be a few changes in file handling (and the grffile package is now obsolete).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Remove grffile actually works!!! Can you make an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is something wrong with the `grffile` package [1]. Org-mode inserts it by default. Apparently it is fixed in the new release of the package (which only loads `graphicx`) but I also haven't received the update containing it.  I opted for removing `grffile` from `org-latex-default-packages-alist`.

[1] https://github.com/ho-tex/grffile/issues/7